# Request.Browser not listed by Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, request, browser

I am writing a program which include a webBrowser control given by Visual Studio 2012. And now I want to get the version of the webBrowser. I found a code example of MSDN:

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
Response.Write("<p>Browser Capabilities:</p>");
Response.Write("Type = " + bc.Type + "<br>");
Response.Write("Name = " + bc.Browser + "<br>");
Response.Write("Version = " + bc.Version + "<br>");
Response.Write("Major Version = " + bc.MajorVersion + "<br>");
Response.Write("Minor Version = " + bc.MinorVersion + "<br>");
Response.Write("Platform = " + bc.Platform + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Beta = " + bc.Beta + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Crawler = " + bc.Crawler + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is AOL = " + bc.AOL + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Win16 = " + bc.Win16 + "<br>");
Response.Write("Is Win32 = " + bc.Win32 + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Frames = " + bc.Frames + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Tables = " + bc.Tables + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Cookies = " + bc.Cookies + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports VB Script = " + bc.VBScript + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports JavaScript = " + bc.JavaScript + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports Java Applets = " + bc.JavaApplets + "<br>");
Response.Write("Supports ActiveX Controls = " + bc.ActiveXControls + "<br>");
Response.Write("CDF = " + bc.CDF + "<br>");
```

But my problem now is: I cannot find Request.Browser. It's not listed by VS2012. I tried to add some .dll reference but it still doesnt work. I hope someone can give me a useful hint where I should look :)

Cheers

EDIT: I already got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
```

Comment: You are using winforms, Request.Browser is only available in web enviroments

Comment: Oh, okay. So I can't get the version in this way?

Comment: You can't while in winforms. The winforms webbrowser control just wraps arround your ie in your system. Change to a mvc or webforms application and you will be able to execute that code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser.aspx) you are talking about Request is in System.Web namespace. `Request` is commonly available as `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` or as property of `Page` (ASP.Net WebForms) or `Controller` (ASP.Net MVC).

But it is not going to help you in your WinForms scenario...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if you are in a web environment:

```
HttpRequest request;
string browser = request.Browser.Browser;
```